# Website building using firebase

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to build a website using only html, css and JavaScript. I have prior knowledge about these stuff. But I want to use Firebase to host the same. Is it possible to do so?

P.S. I don't want to use any JS Framework because I have no prior knowledge.

If answer is no, please do tell me in detail what all should I start learning to do the same.

Comment: It's possible, but depends largely on what you're trying to achieve. What's your definition of done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use Firebase to host your website.

Firebase Hosting:

> Firebase Hosting provides fast and secure static hosting for your web app.
>
> Firebase Hosting is production-grade web content hosting for developers. With Hosting, you can quickly and easily deploy web apps and static content to a global content-delivery network (CDN) with a single command.

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/